# Mostrar todas las variables activas PHP

Tags: php, variables

Necesito saber si alguna funcion de php que me muestre por pantalla todas las variables que hay definidas.

Estoy realizando una integracion en la que dependo de otros archivos a los que no tengo acceso y necesito mostrar todas las variables a las que puedo acceder

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cómo indicas el `get_defined_vars()` te devuelve las distintas variables. Aún así me gustaría dar un poco más de información al respeto siguiendo [la documentación](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php).

En el ejemplo expuesto:

```
<?php
$b = array(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8);

$arr = get_defined_vars();

// print $b
print_r($arr["b"]);

/* print path to the PHP interpreter (if used as a CGI)
 * e.g. /usr/local/bin/php */
echo $arr["_"];

// print the command-line parameters if any
print_r($arr["argv"]);

// print all the server vars
print_r($arr["_SERVER"]);

// print all the available keys for the arrays of variables
print_r(array_keys(get_defined_vars()));
?>
```

Es decir, según los parámetros podéis obtener unas variables específicas o bien obtenerlas y guardalas todas (cómo en el último caso) y poder trabajar con ellas.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias, me viene muy bien esta información

Answer (score 3):

Buscando en diversos sitios, al final he encontrado una solución. Os dejo el código por si alguien mas lo necesita

```
    <?php  
       $vars = get_defined_vars();  
       print_r($vars);  
    ?>
```

Mostrará por pantalla todas las variables, $_POST, $_GET, $_SESSION, $_COOKIES, $_SERVER, y las que hayais definido vosotros